# Angular and jQuery Accordion Reverse Engineering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, accordion

I'm trying to recreate a team/faculty/speaker page that I found for a website I'm making. I'm using Angular to display and search through my JSON, and jQuery to create the hide and show effects of the info associated with each faculty/speaker. From the website that I found it at, I've gotten rid of as much of the JavaScript as I possibly can, while still retaining functionality of the original site, but there's still way to much left and I know I don't need it all. I just can't figure out what else can be taken out, as well as what the variables need to be replaced with. I know the important bits are

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
        function n() {
                        e(".speaker-list-item.active").each(function() {
                            var t = e(this).find(".speaker-bio"),
                                i = t.outerHeight() + 40;
                            e(this).css("margin-bottom", i + "px")
                        })
                    }

                    var l = e(".speaker-list-item .speaker-photo-wrap, .speaker-list-item h3 a");
                    l.on("click", function(t) {
                        t.preventDefault();
                        var i = e(this).parents(".speaker-list-item"),
                            n = i.find(".speaker-bio"),
                            o = n.outerHeight() + 30;
                        i.hasClass("active") ? (i.removeClass("active"), i.css("margin-bottom", "0px"), n.removeClass("active")) : (e(".speaker-list-item").removeClass("active"), e(".speaker-list-item").css("margin-bottom", "0px"), e(
                            ".speaker-bio").removeClass("active"), i.addClass("active"), i.css("margin-bottom", o + "px"), n.addClass("active"))
                    });
});
```

My issue is, having just that as a script at the bottom of the page, doesn't do anything. I've [included a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lNLztvF0wVJoxzonkLut?p=preview) to try and explain my issue a little better and demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can just use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion?

Comment: Definitely not trying to reinvent the wheel, but every typical "accordion" approach I tried when initially trying to recreate the effect in the plunker failed (I'm pretty new to Angular and definitely could have a more solid grasp of vanilla javascript), which is why I tried starting with their code and taking out what was unnecessary. I'm not entirely sure how I'd replicate the functionality of the plunker with the angular accordion.